# Ingest different csv with different fields to an ADX table

Tags: azure-data-explorer

Wondering if its possible to ingest multiple CSV with different number/ type of fields to a single ADX table? (Refer to the csv sample below)

Any way for me to use the header of the csv as the fields?

---

CSV type sample:

**Type A**

```
+--------+-----+--------+
| Name   | Age | Uni    |
+--------+-----+--------+
| Hazriq | 27  | UNITEN |
+--------+-----+--------+
```

**Type B**

```
+------+------+-----+
| Name | Uni  | Age |
+------+------+-----+
| John | UNIx | 31  |
+------+------+-----+
```

**Type C**

```
+------+------+--------------+-----+
| Name | Uni  | Hometown     | Age |
+------+------+--------------+-----+
| Jane | UNIt | Kuala Lumpur | 31  |
+------+------+--------------+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create multiple CSV mappings and provide the applicable mapping for a given  file. You cannot use the CSV headers. Here is an example:

```
.create table demo(name:string, age:int, uni:string, hometown:string)

//define the mappings
.create table demo ingestion csv mapping "typeA" '[{"Name":"name", "Ordinal":0}, {"Name":"age", "Ordinal":1}, {"Name":"uni", "Ordinal":2}]'

.create table demo ingestion csv mapping "typeB" '[{"Name":"name", "Ordinal":0}, {"Name":"uni", "Ordinal":1}, {"Name":"age", "Ordinal":2}]'

.create table demo ingestion csv mapping "typeC" '[{"Name":"name", "Ordinal":0}, {"Name":"uni", "Ordinal":1}, {"Name":"age", "Ordinal":3}, {"Name":"hometown", "Ordinal":2} ]'

//Ingest some test date
.ingest inline into table demo with (csvMappingReference="typeA", pushbypull=true) <| Hazriq,27,UNITEN

.ingest inline into table demo with (csvMappingReference="typeB", pushbypull=true) <| John,UNIx,31

.ingest inline into table demo with (csvMappingReference="typeC", pushbypull=true) <| Jane,UNIt,Kuala Lumpur,31 

//test
demo
```

Comment: are you referring to `csvMappingReference`?

Comment: yes, you can provide a different reference for each ingestion.

Comment: How if I got more than 3 types? Is it possible for me to use the header of the csv as the fields?

Comment: I updated my answer to provide you with an example, CSV headers are not supported for mappings, If the CSV contains headers you should setup a flag to ignore them during ingestion.